# The csv comparison is excluding duplicates in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csvreader

I have two csv files and i am using one csv to search all records from another csv and update its status.
I have two tables and looking for IP and PROTOCOL from search table in input.csv. If it is there, then the EXISTS column is updated to 'No'.
I am stuck where both the protocol and ip are same for two or more records, but they have different port. It is updating only one record.

```
import csv

IP, EXISTS, PROTOCOL = 'IP', 'Exists', 'Protocol'  # Field names referenced.

# Read entire input file into a list.
with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as inp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(inp)
    inputs = list(reader)

# Update input rows that match data in search.csv file.
with open('search.csv', 'r', newline='') as sea:
    sea_reader = csv.DictReader(sea)
    for row in sea_reader:
        protocol, ip = row[PROTOCOL], row[IP]
        for input_ in inputs:
            if input_[PROTOCOL] == protocol and input_[IP] == ip:  # Match?
                input_[EXISTS] = 'No'
                break

# Write updated input.csv data out into a file.
with open('input_updated.csv', 'w', newline='') as outp:
    fieldnames = inputs[0]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outp, fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for input_ in inputs:
        writer.writerow(input_)

print('done')
```

Input.csv

| Name | IP | Protocol | Port | Exists |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| l1 | 192.132.16.02 | HTTP | 80 |  |
| l2 | 192.132.16.03 | SSL | 8443 |  |
| l3 | 192.132.16.03 | SSL | 443 |  |
| l4 | 192.132.16.04 | SSL | 443 |  |

search.csv

| No | Protocol | IP | Port |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HTTP | 192.132.16.02 | 80 |
| 2 | SSL | 192.132.16.03 | 443 |
| 3 | SSL | 192.132.16.03 | 8443 |

Here in search.csv there are two records which has same protocol and ip but different port. In the result it is just including one record and not both. I tried adding port in the condition too but it does not work

Comment: Hi Welcome, use csv.reader() and not csv.DictReader()

Comment: share your desired result

Comment: I expect result to be exactly like input.csv and in 'Exists' column the value for first three rows will be 'No'

Comment: CSV reader does not update at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue in your code is that you `break` out of the loop as soon as you find a match, so you will never find further matches. Removing the `break` will make it work, although it will be slower of course.

One thing is unclear to me: is the port number relevant? In your example the second input line would be matched even if the third search line didn't exist. So it would probably be a good idea to include the port number in the match test:

```
with open('search.csv', 'r', newline='') as sea:
    sea_reader = csv.DictReader(sea)
    for row in sea_reader:
        protocol, ip, port = row[PROTOCOL], row[IP], row[PORT]
        for input_ in inputs:
            if input_[PROTOCOL] == protocol and input_[IP] == ip and input_[PORT] == port:  # Match?
                input_[EXISTS] = 'No'
                break
```

In this case the `break` can remain, cause you will have only exact matches (i.e. input #2 with search #3 and input #3 with search #2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to read the csv files.
Create indexes on both IP, Protocol for both files.
Iterate the search_df and insert value into the Exists column as True if index of search_df is found in input_df. Reset the index and drop nan values.

```
import pandas as pd
input_df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
search_df = pd.read_csv("search.csv")
input_df = input_df.set_index(["IP","Protocol"])
search_df = search_df.set_index(["IP","Protocol"])
for index, _ in search_df.iterrows():
    input_df.loc[index,"Exists"] = True
input_df = input_df.reset_index()
input_df = input_df.dropna()
```